# Why FLAGS is storing a value like other variables

Tags: python

In the following code I am getting the error that None type object has no attribute x. When I run the following code by removing FLAGS it works fine. But I want to assign these values to the FLAGS because in my actual code I want to assign different values to the FLAGS. How can I fix this problem?

```
FLAGS = None
c1 =[1.5, 2.0, 2.5]

for i in range(len(c1)):
    FLAGS.x = c1[i]
    print(FLAGS.x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--x', type=float, default=2.0)
    FLAGS = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code above `if __name__ == '__main__':` is being executed before the FLAGS variable has been initialized. Try something like this

```
import argparse

FLAGS = None
c1 =[1.5, 2.0, 2.5]

def main():
    for i in range(len(c1)):
        FLAGS.x = c1[i]
        print(FLAGS.x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--x', type=float, default=2.0)
    FLAGS = parser.parse_args()
    main()
```

Comment: Is it compulsory to define for loop in main() function? Can I do that without main()

Comment: if you don't want a main function, then you need to move your `for i in range(len(c1)):` loop down below `FLAGS = parser.parse_args()` inside `if __name__ == '__main__':`.